# flash AS6- How to check correct answer in the input box

Tags: flash, math, input

hi I am very new to adobe flash and have been doing a project for my computing class, I am making a game were 2 random generated numbers are displayed and the user must input the value, gaining 10 points if answer is correct. I however am having trouble to get the input text box to work to give me 10 points if the answer is correct, as of right now i only gain points if the 2 generated numbers has a sum of 0. Would really appreciate the help , many thanks. I'll put the code below

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    var Num1:int ;
    var Num2:int ;
    var Answer:int ;
    var Score:int=0;
    var UserInput;



    public function Main() 
    {
        // constructor code
        gotoAndStop(1);
        Start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, StartFunct);

    }

    function StartFunct(e:Event)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,checkFunction);
        }

    function checkFunction(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
         Answer= Num1*Num2;
         if(UserInput == Answer){
             Score=Score+10

         }
         else Score=Score

    }


    function clickhandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Num1  = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        Num2  = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

        num1Box.text = String(Num1);
        num2Box.text = String(Num2);
        UserInput = "";

    }
    function clickhandler2(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Score = Score;

        ScoreBox.text = String(Score);
```

Comment: is `UserInput` of **String** type?? Why not just tell the computer what you mean, `var UserInput : String = "";` ...Anyways I think your problem is the **If** statement in `checkFunction` it should be : `if ( int(UserInput) == Answer)` this tells the computer to consider that text string as an integer (ie: casting as integer)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like this is an ordering issue.  You've got three separate click events firing at the same time.  The ideal way to do this is to make a single click-handler function, and encapsulate your three other functions into that, in precisely the order you want.

Instead of `function StartFunct(e:Event)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,checkFunction);
        }`

Try doing it more like this

```
     function StartFunct(e:Event)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);
        }

function clickHandler(evnt:Event){
function1(); //generate the numbers
function2(); evaluate the numbers and adjust the score
function3(); //adjust score text box
}
```

`
Note that doing this will require you to remove the parameter for your action functions.  You can also just try reordering the way in which you declare your initial onClick eventListeners